# Angular2 Stripe function token() http.post undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, http, post

I've got a problem with Stripe Checkout and Angular2. I use the token() function to post my token.id to the server side but the web console return me "Cannot read property 'post' of undefined".

But I can do http.post in others functions in this component and it works.

Can you help me ?

**component.ts**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {ToastOptions} from "ng2-toasty";
import {Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions} from "@angular/http";
import {Observable} from "rxjs";

@Injectable()
export class CartService {

cart: any = [];

constructor(public http: Http) { }

openCheckout() {
    var handler = (<any>window).StripeCheckout.configure({
        key: 'pk_test_stripe',
        locale: 'auto',
        token: function (token: any) {

            alert(token.id); //This work !

            let client = {
                // client JSON object
            };

            //Cannot read property 'post' of undefined
            this.http.post('PHP script URL', { // This doesn't work !
                products: this.cart,
                client: client,
                stripeToken: token
            }).subscribe(data => {
                    console.log(data);
                }, error => {
                    console.log("Oooops!");
                });
        }
    });

    handler.open({
        name: 'Site demo',
        description: 'Commande',
        currency: 'chf',
        panelLabel: 'Payer {{amount}}',
        amount: 24500
    });

}
```

**component.html**

```
<button (click)="this.cartService.openCheckout()">Stripe</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `fat arrow` for your function like this

```
token: (token: any)=> {...}
```

if you are using function like this

```
token: (token: any)=> {
     //here `this` will work fine, scope of this will present here

}
```

but in case of normal method like this

```
token: function (token: any) { 
    // **this** won't be undefined here but it will refer to this (token) functions instance. The reason why OP is getting undefined is that it tries to select this.http which that functions instance does not have.
}
```

for more info refer here

- https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/arrow-functions.html

Comment: `this` won't be `undefined` under the function it will refer to the token functions instance. The reason OP is getting `undefined` is that it tries to select `this.http` which that functions instance does not have.

Comment: @echonax yes you are right , i get short of words while explaning this, but my logic was same as of you, btw thanks for wording, ill update this in my answer for other one's. thanks

Comment: @PardeepJain no problem :-)